# Alternative solution methods for $y''(x) = e^{y(x)}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Some time ago I came across the following odd looking ODE as an exercise in a textbook. I can't seem to find the source.
$$
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = e^{y(x)} 
\end{equation}
$$

Here $y$ is some function of $x$, I don't think any conditions on $y$ were stated.

I've looked around for other stack posts on this but haven't found one. If this has been discussed before I'd be happy for someone to link me to another post.

The only way I thought of to solve this was to introduce a bunch of substitutions and reduce the order of the ODE. Can anyone else think of another method to solve this? I guess we are dealing with a non-linear ODE so maybe slick solutions are not to be expected.

My method is as follows. First let $u=e^{y(x)}$
$$
\begin{align}
u = e^{y(x)} \implies \frac{du}{dx} = e^y \frac{dy}{dx}\,, \quad \frac{d^2u}{dx^2}= e^y \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + e^y \Big(\frac{dy}{dx}\Big)^2
\end{align}
$$

Rearranging we have
$$
\begin{equation}
\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{1}{u}\frac{du}{dx}\,, \quad \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} = \frac{1}{u} \frac{d^2u}{dx^2}-\frac{1}{u^2}\Big(\frac{du}{dx}\Big)^2
\end{equation}
$$

Now looking at our original equation

\begin{align}
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - e^{y(x)} =0 \\
\end{align}
We rewrite our equation in terms of $u$.
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{u} \frac{d^2u}{dx^2}-\frac{1}{u^2}\Big(\frac{du}{dx}\Big)^2 - u &=0
\end{align}

Now notice that the dependent varible $x$ does not appear in the equation above. We can introduce a new variable $\alpha$ and use the chain rule to reduce the order to get a first order ODE.

let $\alpha = \frac{du}{dx}$

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d\alpha}{dx} = \frac{d^2u}{dx^2} = \frac{d \alpha}{du} \frac{d u}{dx} = \alpha \frac{d\alpha}{du} 
\end{align}
$$

Skipping some algebra our main ODE becomes
$$
\begin{equation}
\frac{\alpha}{u}\frac{d \alpha}{du} - \Big(\frac{\alpha}{u}\Big)^2 - u =0
\end{equation}
$$

Letting $k = \frac{\alpha}{u}$ and doing some more tedious algebra we have a nice simplification.

\begin{equation}
k \frac{dk}{du} = 1
\end{equation}

This is now easily separable we have

\begin{align}
\int k \, dk &= \int du \\
\implies k &= \pm \sqrt{2u +c_1}
\end{align}

Here $c_1$ is an arbitrary constant.
In what follows I'll just consider the positive branch.

Now backtracking we have the following ODE

$$
\begin{equation}
\alpha = \frac{du}{dx} = u \sqrt{2u + c_1}
\end{equation}
$$

Let $\phi = 2u+c_1$

$$
\begin{equation}
\frac{d\phi}{dx} = \sqrt{\phi}(\phi-c_1)
\end{equation}
$$
Introducing yet another substitution... $(\psi = \sqrt{\phi})$

\begin{equation}
2 \frac{d\psi}{dx} = \psi^2 - c_1
\end{equation}
This is again separable

We have

\begin{align}
\int \frac{d \psi}{\psi^2 - c_1} &= \frac{1}{2} \int dx \\
 \implies- \frac{1}{\sqrt{c_1}}\tanh^{-1}\Big(\frac{\psi}{\sqrt{c_1}}\Big) &= \frac{x}{2} + c_2
\end{align}
Leading to...
\begin{equation}
\psi = - \sqrt{c_1} \tanh\big(\sqrt{c_1}\Big(\frac{x}{2}+c_2\Big)\big)
\end{equation}

Back substituting using the definitions of $\psi, \phi$ and $u$ we arrive at

\begin{align}
e^y &=  \frac{c_1}{2}\big(\tanh^2\big(\sqrt{c_1}\Big(\frac{x}{2}+c_2\Big)\big) -1 \big) \\
\implies y(x) &= \ln \Big[\frac{c_1}{2}\big(\tanh^2\big(\sqrt{c_1}\Big(\frac{x}{2}+c_2\Big)\big) -1 \big)\Big]
\end{align}

There will also be a solution for the negative branch.

I also find the method a bit laborious due to all of the new variables I need to define and the mundane algebra. I'm intrigued to know if there is a slicker way.

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+y%27%27+%3D+e%5Ey) agrees with you, and although I don't have the Pro version, its solution starts with multiplying by $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and integrating, which would give you that $\frac{1}{2}(y')^2=e^{y}+c_1$. With some algebra, this can be turned into a separable equation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

\begin{gather*}
\boxed{y^{\prime \prime}-{\mathrm e}^{y}=0}
\end{gather*}

Multiplying the ode by $y^{\prime}$ gives
$$
y^{\prime \prime} y^{\prime}-y^{\prime} {\mathrm e}^{y} = 0
$$
Integrating the above w.r.t $x$ gives
\begin{align*}
\int \left(y^{\prime \prime} y^{\prime}-y^{\prime} {\mathrm e}^{y}\right)d x &= 0 \\ 
\frac{{y^{\prime}}^{2}}{2}-{\mathrm e}^{y} = c_2
\end{align*}
Solving the above for $y^{\prime}$ gives
\begin{align*}
y^{\prime} &= \sqrt{2 \,{\mathrm e}^{y}+2 c_{2}}\tag{1} \\
y^{\prime} &= -\sqrt{2 \,{\mathrm e}^{y}+2 c_{2}}\tag{2} 
\end{align*}
For each one of the above equations, $y$ is found by integration. For example for (1)
Integrating both sides gives
\begin{align*}
\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \,{\mathrm e}^{y}+2 c_{2}}}\,dy &= x + c_1\\
-\frac{\sqrt{2}\, \operatorname{arctanh} \left(\frac{\sqrt{{\mathrm e}^{y}+2 c_{2}}\, \sqrt{2}}{2 \sqrt{c_{2}}}\right)}{\sqrt{c_{2}}} &= x + c_1
\end{align*}
Same for the second $y$ solution. To obtain an explicit $y$, we can take the `tanh` of both sides and extract $y$ then by taking `ln` and simplify if needed.

Comment: This is nicer and avoids all the new variables. Thanks :)